# Why is it that treeView1.SelectedNode points to a node and is not nulled, when before you already have "treeView1.SelectedNode = null" executed?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview

Its seems that

```
treeView1.SelectedNode = null
```

does not work, is it? But before, in sometime through my development, it worked, SelectedNode is nulled and suddenly it doesn't.

Comment: Post more code. May be the surrounding code.

Comment: I think you have to add some more info here, a little hard to understand

Comment: Something else is setting the SelecteNode back? So you have a selection changed event handler? Is SelectedNode bound?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only set the SelectedNode to null if the tree view doesn't have the focus.  As soon as it gets the focus back, the control is going to select the node again.  For example:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        treeView1.SelectedNode = null;
        if (treeView1.SelectedNode == null) Console.WriteLine("okay");
        treeView1.Focus();
        if (treeView1.SelectedNode != null) Console.WriteLine("okay");
    }
```

Output:
okay
okay

This is by design, the native TreeView control really likes having a selection.

Comment: Enough to know that TreeView control behave like that. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to debug this.

```
treeView1.SelectedNode = null;
Debug.Assert(treeView1.SelectedNode == null);
```

Comment: It worked just by adding Debug.Assert(treeView1.SelectedNode == null), and when I commented the "Debug.Assert(treeView1.SelectedNode == null)" just to verify, its working fine, without the problem. What do you think made the treeView1.SelectNode behaved that way?

Comment: Goes back to the problem again even though it has Debug.Assert(treeView1.SelectedNode == null) so it did not help. Thanks any way.

Comment: Debug.Assert does not solve the problem, but it does show that treeView1.SelectedNode = null does succeed. You must be (explicitly or implicitly) selecting a new node at some point later in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in `Shown` event of `yourForm`

```
 private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        treeView1.SelectedNode = null;
 }
```